# How to wrap up dialogs in class?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am developing an android app and I noticed I use the same dialogs in different fragments/Activities.

I was trying to wrap it in a class but my app is crashing whenever is time to show the dialog. Any ideas?

dialog class

```
public class Diaglogs {
+
+    private Context context;
+
+    public Diaglogs(Context context) {
+        this.context = context;
+    }
+
+    public void createPlaylistDialog() {
+        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
+        builder.setTitle("Enter name of the playlist");
+
+        // Set up the input
+        final EditText input = new EditText(context);
+
+        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
+        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
+        builder.setView(input);
+
+        // Set up the buttons
+        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
+            @Override
+            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
+                String playListName = input.getText().toString();
+                if (!"".equals(playListName)) {
+                    Toast.makeText(context, "the c=playlist would be created here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
+                } else {
+
+                }
+            }
+        });
+        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
+            @Override
+            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
+                dialog.cancel();
+            }
+        });
+        builder.show();
+    }
+
+}
```

error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Could you upload activity code also?

Comment: I think the issue is not about showing the alert dialog,check this anwser..http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/1537419

Answer (score 0):

[DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is intended for this purpose.

For simple "ok, no" you may use builder, but with DialogFragment it's easier to handle configuration changes.

PS: for errors always show your stacktace.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurring when you can use one dialog in different type of Activity.

So, You can add specific dialog Theme to your dialog as below example:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
```

Comment: I am actually trying to make one class to hold all my dialogs. Meaning if I have a yes/no dialog call myClass.yesNoDialog() or myClass.inputDialog() So in the activity class I would instantiate MyClass. is there a way to do this?